# PHP localtime - 1 hour

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How can I get localtime - 1 hour?

I can get UTC time - 1 hour with `strtotime('-1 hour')`, but I would like the equivalent for local time.

Ok, problem solved everybody. thanks

Comment: Local time to where? PHP is running on the server, which isn't necessarily in the same time zone as the client.

Comment: `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));` ?

Comment: You could set your server's default_timezone using data_default_timezone_set() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to set the local time before hand?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 1):

make use of settimezone predefine function of php as per your local environment time zone and apply strtotime function